# How do I capture a window close event in an Outlook AppointmentItem?

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

**Background:**
I have created a custom AddIn for Outlook that adds additional functionality to an AppointmentItem. There seems to be an issue however because when I open a new custom appointment and close it without any changes, it always asks me to save my changes. (Code is c#)

[Save Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFBIo.png)

**Question:**
How to I capture the close event *before* it prompts the user to save. That way I can check the item, and determine if it should continue with the save, or close without saving.

**Additional question:**
How does Outlook's AppointmentItem determine if it needs to save or not (Is there a dirty flag on the object, or a changed property collection?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Inspector.Close` event. Item's inspector can be retrieved from the `AppointmentItem.GetInspector` property.

To check the item's dirty state, use the `AppointmentItem.Saved` property.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried adding the following:   ((Outlook.InspectorEvents_Event)inspector).Close += ThisAddIn_Close; However the event gets hit after the "save" dialog is called.